# How do I drain my softener, RO, and acid neutralizer with limited space & vent it properly?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc

I recently installed an acid neutralizer, water softener, and reverse osmosis system in my garage. I have it draining through the wall into my crawlspace tying into the main 4 inch drain line. I have not plumbed it correctly, and need some advice on how to correct my mistake. I need to add a vent (likely a studor vent, since tying into an existing vent will be difficult). I also need to increase my standpipe height to 18". Please see attached photos, and let me know what I need to do (from a professional's point of view)
[image: drain pic 01]

[image: drain pic 02]

[image: drain pic 03]